# remove something from each individual element from the array

Tags: python, list

`'145,153,8,1.35659494835128,155,C,H,H,H,H,H,H,H,H,H,H,H,H,H,C,X,X,X,1.000,0.000,0.000,0.286,0.429,0.000,0.286,0.000,0.286,0.571,0.000,0.143,0.000,0.143,0.000,0.143,0.429,0.286,0,2,0,0,3,1,0,1,3,3,1,0,1,1,0,X,X,X,1,3,0,0,3,1,0,1,3,3,1,0,3,3,0,X,X,X,3,1,3,3,0,3,4,3,0,0,3,4,2,1,4,X,X,X,0.265,0.213,0.523,0.155,0.265,0.052,0.374,0.155,0.290,0.232,0.097,0.381,0.000,0.187,0.174,0.077,0.348,0.213,0.143,0.143,0.000,0.000,0.000,0.143,0.000,0.000,0.000,0.143,0.143,0.000,0.000,0.000,0.143,0.000,0.143,0.000,0.000,0.000,E,E,E,E,E,4,4,3,4,3,3,3,3,3,1,0,1,2,0,3,0.077,0.052,0.039,0.045,0.013,0.065,0.052,0.065,0.026,0.026,0.065,0.058,0.006,0.071,0.058,0.071,0.052,0.019,0.039,0.103,0,0,0,2,-4,-1,2,-2,-3,-3,-3,3,-3,-4,0,2,2,-5,-3,-3,-2,-6,-6,-5,-6,-5,-5,-5,-6,-2,-4,-5,-1,-3,8,-3,-4,-7,-6,-1,0,-2,-1,2,-4,1,4,-3,-1,-3,0,1,0,-1,-3,0,-2,-4,-2,-3,1,-1,0,3,-4,1,2,-2,-1,-3,-4,2,-3,-4,-3,2,0,-5,-3,-2,-3,-5,-5,-5,-4,-4,-5,-6,-5,5,3,-5,4,0,-4,-4,-3,-4,-3,1,1,1,-2,0,-3,-1,5,-3,-2,-1,-2,1,-2,-4,-3,-1,-1,-2,-3,1,1,0,0,1,-4,1,2,-1,-1,-4,-3,4,-3,-5,2,0,0,-5,-4,-3,2,-1,-1,5,-4,0,2,-3,0,-4,-5,0,-4,-4,-2,-1,-1,1,-2,-3,-4,-6,-6,-6,-4,-6,-6,-7,-6,7,1,-6,-1,-3,-6,-5,-4,-6,-4,2,-4,-6,-6,-6,-4,-6,-6,-7,-6,7,1,-6,-1,-3,-6,-5,-4,-6,-4,2,0,-1,-2,1,-5,2,5,-4,-2,-2,-1,2,-3,-5,-2,-2,-1,-5,-3,0,2,1,-1,-1,-4,1,2,-3,-3,-4,-4,5,-3,-5,-2,0,-1,-5,-4,-3,2,-4,-5,-5,-2,-2,-1,-5,-4,-1,5,-4,1,-1,-5,-3,-2,-1,0,-1,-4,-5,-6,-7,-3,-5,-6,-7,-6,2,6,-5,-1,-2,-6,-5,-4,-5,-4,1,-3,3,2,-1,-5,2,4,-3,-2,-5,-4,4,-3,-5,-3,-2,-2,-5,-4,-4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-3,-5,-5,-6,-3,-5,-5,-6,-5,5,2,-5,0,5,-5,-4,-3,-3,-2,3,-4,-5,-5,-6,-6,-4,-5,-6,5,-5,-2,-5,-4,2,-5,-4,-5,-1,9,-5,-3,-3,0,7,-6,1,3,-2,-1,-6,-6,-2,-3,-6,-3,0,-2,-6,-5,-5,-5,-6,-6,-6,-4,-5,-6,-6,-2,2,1,-6,-2,8,-6,-5,-3,-2,2,-2,-1,-1,0,-2,-3,1,2,-3,-1,-3,-4,2,-2,-4,2,2,3,-5,-3,-2,0\n'`
Each individual item in my list consists of something like the above, but with different numbers. I want to keep the first 2 values but get rid of everything else. So for the above example. The final result would be `145,153`. My list size is 145, and I want to do this for every element in my list

Comment: Good to give an example, but please shorten it next time. The question below almost disappears.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
lst = ['145,153,8,1.3565949', '1,2,3,4,5,6', '9,8,7,6,5,4']

[','.join(elem.split(',', 2)[:2]) for elem in lst]
```

returns

```
['145,153', '1,2', '9,8']
```

Comment: Didn't know of that second argument of split! Great :)

Comment: Why can't I accept it straight away, I don't want to wait 2 minutes